# Round Trip cancel return for one person

Tags: air-travel

I purchased one ticket round trip for two people. But one person wants to stay and not come back. So, what should I do? Can i just fly back without him?

Comment: Yes you can fly back without him. Him not flying back as scheduled does not void the ticket, they're not going to turn you away just because you both don't check in together. Call the airline to confirm, they have a copy of your contract of carriage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, 99.9% of the time, this is no problem since you actually have two tickets so only the no show will get cancelled.

I have seen, and been party too, similar circumstances a number of times with no consequence to the traveling parties.

For the nitpickers, this is from experience and industry knowledge.  There is nothing to reference since the airlines don't publish rules for such corner cases.

Comment: But I don't have two separate tickets. it is one round trip ticket for two people so it is one itinerary.

Comment: @VitaliiMaximov  Unless you're flying super low budget carrier with non-normative processes, each of you does have you own ticket.  Several people can share an Itinerary, but that Itin links to the individual tickets.  Itineraries and tickets are two different things.

Comment: I am flying very cheap ticket via Tarom airlines, who are also very cheap. So, I probably should just contact them.

Comment: @VitaliiMaximov  Sure, ask them what happens if one person is a no-show.  But, Tarom is a member of SkyTeam so they have to follow most normal industry practices.

Comment: @VitaliiMaximov you and your traveling companion are probably on the same *booking,* but not on the same ticket.  Look at the ticket number.  Tarom is a Sky Team member so they will follow the normal standards.  The ticket number should be a thirteen- or fourteen-digit number starting with 281.  You should find that you and your companion have different ticket numbers.

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt to check in online if possible well before the flight.